# Как добавить в lazy load background?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, background, lazyloading

Стоит плагин на wp [lazy-load](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/lazy-load/), но не работают изображения через стили background.

Может, кто то сталкивался?

Вытянул код из плагина `lazy-load.js`

```
(function($) {
lazy_load_init();
$( 'body' ).bind( 'post-load', lazy_load_init ); // Work with WP.com infinite scroll

function lazy_load_init() {
    $( 'img[data-lazy-src]' ).bind( 'scrollin', { distance: 200 }, function() {
        lazy_load_image( this );
    });

    // We need to force load gallery images in Jetpack Carousel and give up lazy-loading otherwise images don't show up correctly
    $( '[data-carousel-extra]' ).each( function() {
        $( this ).find( 'img[data-lazy-src]' ).each( function() {
            lazy_load_image( this );
        } );        
    } );
}

function lazy_load_image( img ) {
    var $img = jQuery( img ),
        src = $img.attr( 'data-lazy-src' );

    if ( ! src || 'undefined' === typeof( src ) )
        return;

    $img.unbind( 'scrollin' ) // remove event binding
        .hide()
        .removeAttr( 'data-lazy-src' )
        .attr( 'data-lazy-loaded', 'true' );

    img.src = src;
    $img.fadeIn();
}
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Вот этот точно умеет https://wordpress.org/plugins/lazysizes/

Comment: Он на базе вот этого js https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes - по ссылке описание